# Janrain (RPX) basic setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, janrain, rpxnow, rpx

I might be thickheaded but I can't seem to get the Janrain (former RPX) to work. I have done the following:

- Signed up and followed the stuff they need you to fill out.
- Download the sample code (c#)
- At my token site (mydomain.com/user/login) I have in the controller added the following call:    `var res = new Rpx("{myapi}", "http://{mysiteid}.rpxnow.com").AuthInfo("{mydomain.com/user/login");`
- Made sure that localhost is whitelisted

Whenever I try to call

```
var res = new Rpx("{myapi}", "http://{mysiteid}.rpxnow.com").AuthInfo("{mydomain.com/user/login")
```

I receive the error that the data is invalid on the following line:

```
doc.Load(dataStream);
```

[image]

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

I misunderstood the token, since they use token as the same term as the url it will do a postback to. I could get it to work by the following:

```
   var token = Request.Form["token"];
   var res = new Rpx("xxx", "http://{mysiteid}.rpxnow.com").AuthInfo(token);
```